# Changing Default "input is not in a correct format" Validation Error in RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, wcf-ria-services, validationattribute

I'm trying to change the default error message in a Silverlight DataGrid when the input is in an incorrect format. For example, you type letters into a numerical field. As you tab away, it says "input is not in a correct format." I've seen how to fix this, and that is to put a validation attribute on it with a custom error message. Problem is, my object is coming from RIA services. It seems to ignore my custom error message from my validation attributes. Is there something I need to do to expose this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have the metadata set up for your objects.
[using metadata for validation in silverlight](http://mwoodhall.wordpress.com/2009/11/28/using-metadata-for-validation-in-silverlight/)
This will create it for you and bring the annotation to the silverlight project.

Answer (score 1):

Validation attributes/metadata attributes won't help here because the error happens on the control and not on the property.
The control is not able to call the setter of type `int` (or any other numeric type) because the string value cannot be cast.
I'd also like to know you can change the default error message...

A possible workaround is to use a custom TextBox that only allows numeric input, that looks something like this:

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    public NumericTextBox()
    {
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(NumericTextBox_KeyDown);
    }

    void NumericTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Shift || e.Key == Key.Escape || e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Delete)
            return;

        if (e.Key < Key.D0 || e.Key > Key.D9)
        {
            if (e.Key < Key.NumPad0 || e.Key > Key.NumPad9)
            {
                    e.Handled = true;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that works is this (this is on the client side):

```
public partial class MyEntity        
{
    public string MyField_string
    {
        get
        {
            return MyField.ToString();
        }
        set
        { 
            decimal res = 0;
            var b = Decimal.TryParse(value, out res);
            if (!b)
                throw new ArgumentException("Localized message");
            else
                this.MyField = Math.Round(res, 2);
        }
    }

    partial void OnMyFieldChanged()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyField_string");
    }
}
```

And then bind to MyField_string instead of MyField.